# How to pass multiple arguments to Ionic reorder directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm basing the issue on the following codepen: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/JsHjf

It uses: `<ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reoder="moveItem(item, fromIndex, toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>` and it is working just fine.

I want to move whole `<ion-item>` into a directive. Here is my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/w61yqfuCypliugToUD3E?p=preview and some essential code parts:

```
directive("myitem", function() {
  return {
    restrict : "E",
    scope : {
      item : "=",
      onItemDelete : "&",
      moveItem : "&"
    },
    templateUrl : "MyItemTemplate"
  }
})
```

```
<ion-item>
  {{ item.id }}
  <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="onItemDelete({'item': item})"></ion-delete-button>
  <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveItem({'item' : item, 'fromIndex' : fromIndex, 'toIndex' : toIndex})"></ion-reorder-button>
</ion-item>
```

I know how to pass multiple parameters thanks to that question: [AngularJS directive binding a function with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973507/angularjs-directive-binding-a-function-with-multiple-arguments)

However the **fromIndex** and **toIndex** are not propagated

```
  $scope.moveItem = function(item, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    console.log("moveItem: ", item, fromIndex, toIndex);
    console.log("unfortunately, the fromIndex and toIndex are undefined");
    $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
  };
```

---

I tried looking into the source, moving up to the call stack but I cannot spot any obvious blunders there.

[image]

---

So yes, I would really like to take benefit of reorder-able list while keeping it into a separate directive.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the name of the parameter you're passing matters. You want to have:

```
 on-reorder="moveItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"
```

Comment: I'm getting ```0``` and ```0``` regardless the item I move. I believe it has something to do with the fact that ```ion-item``` sits within ```myitem``` as the very first child (hence index 0). Can you please verify?

Comment: Ah, that's do it. You may want to take a deeper look at that listItem directive.