# Pass function from controller scope to directive isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I am using AngularJS and am trying to pass a function on my controller's scope to a directive's isolate scope.

I know I have done this before, but am having issues this time.

The function takes two inputs, and logs them to the console.

However, when I pass it to my directive as

```
<div my-dir my-function="functionName"></div>
```

or

```
<div my-dir my-function="functionName()"></div>
```

And attempt to call it from my directives controller, I actually get a function that takes no arguments and returns my function.

that is, instead of calling

```
ctrl.functionName(a,b)
```

I have to call

```
ctrl.functionName()(a,b)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have seen some reference to syntax like this:

```
 <div my-dir my-function="functionName({})"></div>
```

Comment: https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-am

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973507/angularjs-directive-binding-a-function-with-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:

```
<div my-dir my-function="functionName()"></div>
```

directive:

```
angular.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      callback: '&myFunction'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.callback({param1: val1, param2: val2});
  };
});
```

Comment: Using this notation with the parameter dictionary worked. Why is this necessary? Also, I had to pass in the method to the directive with the argument names

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code with scope isolation:

```
angular.module("Demo", [])  
  .controller("ChildCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.testFunc = function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
 })
.directive("isoElement", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        testFunc: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log(scope.testFunc()(1, 2));
    }
  };
});
```

Directive usage will be:

```
<div ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
    <iso-element test-func="testFunc"></iso-element>
</div>
```

You will need to do scope.testFunc()(..) because scope.testFunc() will return the function itself. IMO this is more understandable than approaching the problem from another side.

Comment: My problem was I didn't understand why I had to call testFunc()(), when testFunc is a function that returns a value, not a function.

The correct answer seems to be calling the function from within the directive this notation

    testFunc({arg1:1,arg2:2})

Comment: In that case, "&" passes only the reference and using "=" passes the whole function. When the reference is passed then we need to first get the function itself and then invoke it. On the othe rhand if we use "=" in scope isolation then we get the function itself in the scope and can simply call it.