# Invoking function breaks scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

Same issue as here: [AngularJS directive binding a function with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973507/angularjs-directive-binding-a-function-with-multiple-arguments)

Following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26244600/2892106

In as small of a nutshell as I can.

This works:

```
<my-directive on-save="ctrl.saveFn"></my-directive>
```

With:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.saveFn = function(value) { vm.doSomethingWithValue(value); }
});
```

But when I convert to Typescript and use real classes, this breaks.

```
class MyController {
  constructor() {}

  saveFn(value) {
    this.doSomethingWithValue(value);
  }
}
```

In the Typescript version when debugging, "this" is referencing the Window global. So my scope is messed up somehow, but I don't know how to fix it. How can I get "this" to refer to MyController as expected?

Comment: How is saveFn called?

Comment: Inside of constructor, you can do `this.saveFn = this.saveFn.bind(this);`. An annoying solution but it works.

Comment: In the directive invocation. So in the directive like this: `<select on-change="$ctrl.onSave()($ctrl.someValue)">` It's that invoking that I think is the culprit, I just don't know why.

Comment: @CoryDanielson rad that works. Add an answer and I'll credit it to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my scope is messed up somehow

Use an arrow function instead of a method.

## Fixed

```
class MyController {
  constructor() {}

  saveFn = (value) => {
    this.doSomethingWithValue(value);
  }
}
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: This works, and thanks for the link! I had made the assumption that methods on a class would not need to be a fat arrow function.