# Pass params to function inside AngularJS template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to know, how to pass params to function dynamically inside AngularJS template.
I have many rows in table and each row has a button **Add deposit**. I would like to pass row number to this button's ng-click function.

Here is snippet of my template:

```
<div id="documentsTable" class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="document in data">
        <tr>
            ...
            <td>
                ...
                <button ng-show="document.depositCheckbox" ng-click="addDeposit({id: document.number})" id="addDepositBtn"
                        type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add deposit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('documentDirective', ['$compile', '$templateCache', function () {
return {
    templateUrl: 'templates/documentTemplate.html',
    scope: {
        data: '=',
        addDeposit: '&'
    },
    restrict: 'E'
}}]);
```

And in my HTML file I have:

```
<document-directive data="documents" add-deposit="addDeposit()"></document-directive>
```

Function addDeposit in my controller:

```
$scope.addDeposit = function(documentId) {
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.documents.length; i++) {
        if($scope.documents[i].number == documentId) {
            var depositLength = $scope.documents[i].deposit.length;
            var deposit = {'number': depositLength, 'value': 0, 'paymentDate': new Date(), 'firstRow': false};
            $scope.documents[i].deposit.push(deposit);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so as I understand it, you are trying to get which row that you are getting the post request from?

I think you should be able to do that with the `$index` property of the ng-changed.

So something like:

```
<button ng-show="document.depositCheckbox" ng-click="addDeposit({id: document.number, rowNumber: $index})" id="addDepositBtn"
                        type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add deposit</button>
```

EDIT:
Try this instead then:

```
<button ng-show="document.depositCheckbox" ng-click="addDeposit()(document.number)" id="addDepositBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Add deposit</button>
```

And where you pass the function in:

```
<document-directive data="documents" add-deposit="addDeposit"></document-directive>
```

Passing in method as parameter:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26244600/1958344

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problem, because my **id: document.number** store rowNumber. The problem is that in my addDeposit function I can't get this value - it is undefined.

Comment: It looks like:
I declared in my HTML element, that function addDeposit() has no parameters, so I can't pass any parameters to this function, when I use it in my template.

Comment: No that should not have anything to do with it, since you don't have to declare the variables there. Can you post some of the controller code, where you define the `addDeposit` function?